# QGIS crashes on exit()

Tags: qgis-2, command-line

Here his my test code

```
import os
print("in qgis, quitting")
os.sys.exit()
```

When i execute it in QGIS2.0 with line `qgis --nologo --code q.py` it shows an error on line 3 `os.sys.exit()`

Can you tell me what is wrong with this?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: `An error occured executing the following code:
execfile('q.py')


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "q.py", line 3, in 
    os.sys.exit()
SystemExit
`